# Inconveniente con la Función Potencia y Tasa Nominal

Tags: excel, vba

Cordial saludo equipo. Quiero pedirles el favor con lo siguiente correspondiente a las funciones Potencia y Tasa  Nominal en Excel VBA., tengo dos problemas en el calculo de un resultado haciendo uso de esas funciones:

Código función potencia:

```
Range("G8").Value = (Exp(1 + Range("B7").Value, (1 / Range("F6").Value) - 1))
```

Al ejecutar dicho código me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Error de compilación:

El número de argumentos es incorrecto o la asignación de propiedad no es valida
```

Vale mencionar  que he buscado en internet y veo que la función  Exp, es para el calculo de las potencias y los parámetros de la función son:

```
=Exp(x,y)
```

El segundo caso es con la funcion de Tasa Nominal, en donde al poner:

```
Range("H8").Value = (WorksheetFunction.Nominal(Range("B7").Value, Range("F6").Value) / Range("B7").Value)
```

Pese a que no me muestra error, no me da el resultado que espero.

y al poner

```
Range("H8").Value = (TASA.Nominal(Range("B7").Value, Range("F6").Value) / Range("B7").Value)
```

me muestra lo siguiente:

```
Se ha producido el siguiente error '424' en tiempo de ejecución : Se requiere un objeto
```

En verdad no se a que se deben esos dos errores, muchas gracias por su colaboración!.

Comment: Qué es `TASA` en `TASA.Nominal(...)` ? Qué valores hay en B7 y F6 cuando calculas esa exponencial?

Answer (score 1):

La función EXP, según la documentación oficial tiene un único argumento y tú le estás pasando 2:

> [Función
> EXP](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/exp-function)

El error que te da TASA es porque no es ningún objeto creado por defecto en VBA, como puede ser el objeto Application, Thisworkbook, ActiveSheet, Activecell, etc. Tienes que crearlo antes con la instrucción `Dim` especificando qué tipo de objeto va a ser. Por ejemplo, `Dim TASA as Worksheet` lo crea como hoja de cálculo.

> [Instrucción
> Dim](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement)

Como no está definido de ninguna manera, por eso te dice "se requiere un objeto", porque no sabe lo que es.

Para evitar errores de código, procura siempre poner al principio de todo `Opcion Explicit` que es una instrucción que **obliga** a declarar variables si las usas.

> [Option Explicit (Instrucción, Visual
> Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement)